# Are specificity and selectivity independent variables in regard to bayes's rules?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I was trying to refresh my memory of bayes rule.

As far as I understand,

```
P(test is true| X) = sensitivity.
P(test is false|X) = specificity.
```

(Let me know if the above understanding is wrong)

Then I was unable to see if the following relationship should hold:

```
specificity = 1 - sensitivity
```

If not then some examples of where they are correlated and where they are not will be appreciated.

Lastly, if they have some correlation: does P(X) play a role in their correlation.